# How to add non azure vm into VSTS Deployment groups

Tags: azure-devops, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As we know we can add azure vm as a machine into our VSTS deployment group using the PowerShell script which VSTS provides. Based on that we can create new release definition and add our machine into pipeline.

Question is there any way to add **non azure vm** into VSTS deployment group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script that is provided is agnostic to cloud providers and can be used on any machine with powershell and internet connectivity.

Comment: Great today I will check it and let you know the status.